# Showing multiple templates within a single modal dialog

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js, modal-dialog, handlebars.js

I am using bootstrap modal dialog in ember.
I render it as a view from the controller.

```
this.set("modalView", app.AddModalView.create({
controller: this,
templateName: "firstModalScreen"
}));
this.get("modalView").append();
```

My problem is that I want to show another template in this view upon some action in this first template. For Example, choosing something in firstModalScreen takes you to the details of the particular chosen item and should render say, secondModalScreen. 
The behavior is just like navigating from one route to another but I want to achieve this within the modal dialog. What is the best way to do this?

I could hide the first modal and then render it again with another template, but that causes an unnecessary close and open of same dialog.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not doing this with basic ember routes?  Did you have some trouble doing it that way?

Comment: Well, this workflow is sort of a prerequisite for another workflow and so it gives a better UI experience if its a modal dialog than a regular page.

Comment: Ember routes can be within modals...

Comment: Thanks you @gravityplanx, this gave the clue and I am now able to show multiple templates without closing and opening the dialog again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a similar feature recently. I ended up solving it using Ember's Container View nested in a {{view}} helper inside the modal view. You can check out my JSBIN at  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ruzog/5/edit, or the whole ramble at  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21733148/swapping-a-child-template-within-a-modal

EDIT:

Upated example:http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ruzog/6/edit

Here's the crucial bit of code. The container view observes a property on the shared context. As user activity alters the state of the model, the container view will dynamically update it's content with a new template/view/controller.

```
App.ChildContainerView = Ember.ContainerView.extend({
  classNames: ['child-div'],
  didInsertElement: function() {
    this.updateContent();
  },

  updateContent: function() {
    console.log('Update content');
    this.removeObject(this.get('childViews')[0]);
    if(this.get("context.name") == "Jimi"){
      this.pushObject(App.ModalChildView.create());    
    } else {
      this.pushObject(App.AlternateChildView.create());
    }
  }.observes('context.name') 
});
```

Comment: In your example, you are not changing the content dynamically while the modal dialog is open. I need to change the content (the whole layout) while the dialog remains open.

Comment: In the JSBin this is true, I was just trying to lay out the building blocks in the simplest/clearest way. In my actual feature implementation I used the same technique to create a modal view that has a Table of Contents on the left in one panel, and depending on which item is selected therein the 'content' area to the right is updated inline. I'll try and make an updated JSBin if I get a chance this afternoon.

Comment: thanks for your answer @pjfingers. The updated JSBin is what I need. I however managed to get it working without nested views since I am replacing the whole screen and not just part of it. I will however accept your answer since it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the content within the modal. I've done this before by simply adding a boolean and having handlebars display certain content. If you want to show more than 2 screens, you might have to use a number and extend a handlebars function that can be use a switch statement to test for different values to show different content

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='modal-popup'>
<div id="popup" class="modal fade unselectable" style="display:none;">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                Modal Title
            </div>
            <span class="unselectable">
                 <!-- User input (Part that changes)-->
                 {{partial "_data-entry"}}

            </span>
            <div id="footer">
                {{!Code for footer}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name='_data-entry'>
  {{#if editingMode}}
    {{!Show editing mode content}}
  {{else}}
    {{!Show other stuff}}
  {{#if}}
</script>
```

Comment: This method seems quiet cumbersome when there are a lot of actions involved :(